# Duplicate MySQL Parent Child records

Tags: mysql

I've got a MySQL table:

- id
- name
- parent_id
- version

parent_id is a Foreign key to id in the same table.

I would like to duplicate all records where version = 1 to version = 2 while keeping the parent / child structure.

When I use this query:

```
INSERT INTO 
    table 
    (
        name,
        parent_id,
        version
    )
SELECT
    name,
    parent_id,
    2
FROM 
    table
WHERE 
    version = 1
```

The new records (ofcourse) become children of the old ones... So, how can I set parent_id to be the newly created record?

Comment: _children_ is the correct term.

Comment: If the parent_id must store in the "level 1" record the value of the id of the new "level 2" record, I would use a procedure with a cursor. Please confirm what is exactly required...

Answer (score 1):

You can try and develop a mapping strategy where you figure out what the new IDs are and map back to them, or you can simply offset the new IDs by a certain amount:

```
INSERT INTO `table` (id, name, parent_id, version)
  SELECT id+10000, name, parent_id+10000, 2
  FROM `table`
  WHERE version=1
```

In this case, 10000 would be greater than `SELECT MAX(id)` from that table. You could write this as a single statement if you locked the table, computed the max, and did the insert.
4

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
INSERT INTO 
    table 
    (
        name,
        parent_id,
        version
    )
SELECT
    name,
    id,
    2
FROM 
    table
WHERE 
    version = 1
```

Comment: Use the `{}` button to format code, or indent it with four spaces.

Comment: Also isn't this exactly the same as in the question?

Comment: I just replaced the parent_id by id, since he want to link it with the id of the parent. Thanks for formatting the code. I am still new here...

Comment: That's okay. I still think you're missing the point of the question, though. This is a non-trivial thing if you start out with a mass-insert as you still need to remap old `parent_id` values to new `parent_id` values.